# cache static content to client browser like (images,icons)

Tags: caching, browser-cache, image-caching, clientcache

Can anyone guide me how can I cache my static content like logo icons folder to client browser with expiry time period ..

that is what Im trying only

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="60" VaryByParam="None" %>
```

Comment: Have UserControl(.ascx) with only image you want to cache and apply above OutputCache attribute in it or check this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22888/Caching-Images-in-ASP-NET

Comment: thanks @malkam .. that content is not helping for me